# Div width in zoomed chrome browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Open this link in chrome browser http://jsfiddle.net/A8fhT/3/ and see element width (270), next make  zoom out (ctrl + "-") and now see width (269). On Firefox everything is ok, any solution for chrome, or this is bug?

Edit:
A.K example http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/5E9kj/
Image: http://s7.postimage.org/qgezkqcor/image.png

Comment: Working fine... http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/5E9kj/

Comment: @A.K : try and unzoom (ctr + "-") check still problem..

Comment: @galer : you are right.... i have tried its giving 268 and 269... working fine on FF version 12 and current Chrome version is 20.xx.xxx

Comment: @galer88: Very strange behavior by chrome, while using `display:block` instead of `position:absolute` it fixes the problem on zoom out, but on zoom in it show width `271px` See this: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/9R3cs/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was only with absolute positioned elements, so I modified jQuery function (// lines).

```
    function getWidthOrHeight(elem, name, extra) {

        //deletes position//
        var $elem = $(elem); //
        var position = $elem.css('position'); //
        $elem.css('position', ''); //

        // Start with offset property
        var val = name === "width" ? elem.offsetWidth : elem.offsetHeight,
        i = name === "width" ? 1 : 0,
        len = 4;

        if (val > 0) {
            if (extra !== "border") {
                for (; i < len; i += 2) {
                    if (!extra) {
                        val -= parseFloat(jQuery.css(elem, "padding" + cssExpand[i])) || 0;
                    }
                    if (extra === "margin") {
                        val += parseFloat(jQuery.css(elem, extra + cssExpand[i])) || 0;
                    } else {
                        val -= parseFloat(jQuery.css(elem, "border" + cssExpand[i] + "Width")) || 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            //sets position//
            $elem.css('position', position); //

            return val + "px";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the lead front-end developer at [geni.com](http://www.geni.com) working primarily on the [HTML5 tree](https://www.geni.com/family-tree/html5#100594125).

I have worked extensively with `zoom`, but haven't been able to get consistent behavior across all browsers. However, I've found that CSS transform's `scale` is far more reliable than zoom.

If you really need zoom, try applying `scale` to `$(body)` (or any other element). I was able to get consistent widths in Chrome & FF.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5E9kj/7/)**

Comment: I don't need zoom, but user can do ctrl-(for some reason) and then application gets wrong width.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a solution.

I create a hidden canvas object and inside of it, I include the divs with the width problem. Once the page is loaded, I extract the divs from canvas (unwrap) and everything looks great at any zoom level!

Hope it helps!